# file_get_contents doesn't work but fsockopen works

Tags: php, file-get-contents, fsockopen

I've installed php 5.3.14 on Ubuntu Desktop 12.04.

with:
    allow_url_fopen = 1

Doesn't work bellow:

```
<?php
echo file_get_contents('http://www.example.com');
```

Works bellow:

```
<?php
$fp = fsockopen("www.example.com", 80, $errno, $errstr, 30);
if (!$fp) {
    echo "$errstr ($errno)<br />\n";
} else {
    $out = "GET / HTTP/1.1\r\n";
    $out .= "Host: www.example.com\r\n";
    $out .= "Connection: Close\r\n\r\n";
    fwrite($fp, $out);
    while (!feof($fp)) {
        echo fgets($fp, 128);
    }
    fclose($fp);
}
```

Even curl_exec() works.
I've also tried like this with Python, Python could fetch www contents.

I'm not using Firewall, Proxy.

But no problem with local network.
(192.168.1.36 is my local server machine.)

```
<?php
echo file_get_contents('http://192.168.1.36);
```

Is any configuration or installation problems?
Thanks.

Comment: What's the error when `file_get_contents` doesn't work?

Comment: And with full error reporting turned on, you get no errors? - Hard to believe.

Comment: @Leigh and `error_reporting(E_ALL);`

Comment: @MrCode error is `PHP Warning: file_get_contents(http://www.example.com/): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! in /path/to/test.php on line 14`

Answer (score 1):

One of the answers are:

You need to also check in PHP.ini file

```
extension = php_openssl.dll
```

If it is enable or not, if not then just enable that by removing ";" sign

Answer (score 0):

This is a simular question:

[PHP file_get_contents does not work on localhost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8423404/php-file-get-contents-does-not-work-on-localhost)

Check the answer and then it should work

Comment: Thank you for telling a similar question. But unfortunately `file_get_contents` **works** on local network including localhost with my environment...