# How to fetch a variable (that is a url) into a iframe src?

Tags: php, javascript, html

here is what I'm trying to accomplish:

I have a file called url.php. When I access this file the only thing that shows up is a url.

I wanted to fetch this url and use it as a variable on a iframe in a different page.

Here is what I got:

```
<?php
$myvar = file_get_contents('http://localhost/url.php');
echo "<iframe src='$myvar' height="1800px" width="1900px" frameborder="0"></iframe>";
?>
```

But it doesnt seem to be working.

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_LNUMBER, expecting
```

Any suggestions? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You need to watch your double quotes.

```
echo "<iframe src='$myvar' height='1800px' width='1900px' frameborder='0'></iframe>";
```

You also may be having issues since you're using it on `localhost`:

[PHP file_get_contents does not work on localhost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8423404/php-file-get-contents-does-not-work-on-localhost)

Comment: That seems to work but it loads for a long time and doesnt update the iframe src url. The Src remains blank.

Comment: Just try `echo $myvar;` and see what comes through.

Comment: echo $myvar; doesnt show anything. So I assume there is something wrong with the file get contents

Comment: What happens when you visit the page in a web browser?

Comment: The page where im getting my var or the page with the loaded script?

Comment: OK. I updated my answer with a link about using `file_get_contents` on `localhost`. Maybe check that out and see if you need to change something.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I've uploaded to my host and the problem is still there.

Answer (score 0):

When echo'ing with variables inside always double check your quotes.

Try this:

```
echo "<iframe src='".$myvar."' height='1800px' width='1900px' frameborder='0'></iframe>";
```

Comment: Seems like its not fetching properly the $myvar

Comment: Then its a problem with `file_get_contents`

Comment: Any suggestion what could be wrong with it? The url.php is displaying a URL as content just fine.

Comment: Post the content of the url.php, try also having them in the same directory and calling with relative path (without `http://localhost`)