# simple_html_dom not finding my element

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

I'm trying prices off of Amazon for an exercise.

```
      <?php
      require('simple_html_dom.php');
      $get = $_GET['id'];
      $get_url = 'http://www.amazon.co.uk/s/field-keywords='.$get;
       echo $get_url;
      // Retrieve the DOM from a given URL
      $html = file_get_html($get_url);

      foreach($html->find('li[class=newp]') as $e) 
        echo $e->plaintext . '<br>';
```

I tried a few differents:

li[class=newp]

.price

ul[class=rsltL]

but it doesn't return anything, what am I doing wrong?

I tried returning the titles as well:

.lrg.bold

Tried Xpath, nothing.

Thanks

Comment: No problem here. I get results. What `id` are you using? (I uses URL `http://www.amazon.co.uk/s/field-keywords=11`)

Comment: i was using blacklist

Comment: @Rik with this       foreach($html->find('li[class=newp]') as $e) 
 you get results?

Comment: With your exact code i got result for id=blacklist (http://www.amazon.co.uk/s/field-keywords=blacklist).

Comment: Can you do a `echo $html;` after the `file_get_html` and see in the source if you get some `class="newp"`?

Comment: For some reason, that class is called newPrice instead of newp. Sorry about this and thanks for your help. It was driving me mad

Comment: Nice. The class here is still called "newp" so you should check for localization, browser-version or something. Maybe it's the User-Agent-string Amazon checks and gives different results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is fine. It is very likely that your PHP settings are the culprits.

put

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
```

at the begining of your php script and see if it prints out any useful error.

Also, note that simple_html_dom uses the `file_get_contents()` function internally to grab page content.  So, you may want to run `file_get_contents($get_url)` to see what happens.

If that function does not work then it is definitely your PHP setting.  In such case, I recommend starting another thread with that issue in the title.

This might help though:
[PHP file_get_contents does not work on localhost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8423404/php-file-get-contents-does-not-work-on-localhost)