# file_get_contents does not work on localhost

Tags: php, codeigniter

file_get_contents isn't working when the url is from localhost (file_get_contents("http://localhost:9000")).

I tried file_get_contents(*link to google*) to test it and works perfectly.

also tried using the 127.0.0.1:9000 address and was not successful.

The same project hosted on a different url also works.

allow_url_fopen is on, extension=php_openssl.dll is enabled.

using:

"$domain = array(*link to local host*);"

or curl to load the url also does not work only on localhost.

PS: URLs can be accessed normally using browser.

Code on Controller:
Code:

```
$my_var = file_get_contents('http://localhost:9000'); // timeout here only if localhost
var_dump($my_var);
die();
```

Comment: Please provide some code. And are you able to just visit the URL in the browser?

Comment: what are you tried already?

Comment: @Koen Yes, I'm able to normally access the URLS in the browser. Code added to the post

Comment: Are there any errors, warnings or notices?

Comment: @koen Only timeout after X seconds defined on php.ini. For other urls(or same url in different server) works instantly.

Comment: Isn't it `file_get_contents`'ing itself then? (Which creates an endless loop of requests that eventually result in a timeout)

Comment: check this similar question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8423404/php-file-get-contents-does-not-work-on-localhost

Comment: @koen No, because the controller that is calling the function file_get_contents(localhost) is in a different page ( localhost/something/something)

Comment: @RaviPatel Thanks for the comment, I found that question earlier and did everything that was proposed there, such as "allow_url_fopen" and "php_openssl.dll". And it also did not work.