# how to access data from one website to other using api and json

Tags: php, json

I have a page where i get whole data from database
    http://localhost/staff/home.php

```
if($btn_search =='Serach' && $btn_search !='') {
 $search_field  =  isset($_GET['search_field'])?$_GET['search_field']:'';
 $all_users = $obj->getAllUsers($search_field);


 }else{
 $all_users = $obj->getAllUsers();
 $r = json_encode($all_users);
 echo "<pre>";
 print_r($r);
 die();
 }
```

here got the data in JSON format.
but now i want same data in other website and the path is

```
http://localhost/staff_json/
```

and the code i have done like this

```
<?php
$rs = file_get_contents('http://localhost/staff/home.php');

$obj = json_decode($rs);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($obj);
 ?>
```

the page is successfully run but data is not showing.
please help me if someone know this

Comment: check this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8423404/php-file-get-contents-does-not-work-on-localhost) -- anyway, what does `var_dump($rs)` gave you?

Answer (score 2):

In your http://localhost/staff/home.php in your else part:

```
else{
  $all_users = $obj->getAllUsers();
  $r = json_encode($all_users);
  echo $r;
}
```

Updated my code as per your JSON:

put below JSON on "http://localhost/staff/home.php" as it is (actually this is your JSON output you are getting from your code)

```
[{
    "id": "94",
    "username": "jems",
    "password": "123",
    "email": "jems@gmail.com",
    "mobile": "8596558499",
    "address": "Banglor",
    "gender": "male",
    "salary": "0",
    "status": "1",
    "image_name": "1320294973-screenshot.jpg"
}, {
    "id": "99",
    "username": ".sapna",
    "password": "sapna9",
    "email": "sapnapapola15@gmail.com",
    "mobile": "8826089668",
    "address": "laxminagar",
    "gender": "male",
    "salary": "0",
    "status": "1",
    "image_name": "no-image.jpg"
}]
```

And below is the code your "http://localhost/staff_json/index.php"

```
<?php

$rs = file_get_contents("http://localhost/staff/home.php");
$obj = json_decode($rs);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($obj);

?>
```

I am getting the desired output

[image: jsonfile]

[image: calling[![][2]]][3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lnCS0.png)

[image]

AS per your code:

Prepare a separate file "userdata.php" place it to same folder where the "home.php" page /staff/userdata.php

```
<?php
include('config/controller.php');
    $obj =   new Controller();
    $all_users = $obj->getAllUsers();
    $r = json_encode($all_users);
    echo $r;

?>
```

And below is the code your "http://localhost/staff_json/index.php"

```
<?php

$rs = file_get_contents("http://localhost/staff/userdata.php");
$obj = json_decode($rs);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($obj);

?>
```

Then you get the desired output:

Below is your "home.php" page PHP script:

```
<?php
include('config/controller.php');
$obj =   new Controller();
include('header.php');

 $obj->authenticate();

$all_users = '';
$search_field ='';
 $btn_search  = isset($_GET['btn_search'])?$_GET['btn_search']:'';
 if($btn_search =='Serach' && $btn_search !='') {
     $search_field  =  isset($_GET['search_field'])?$_GET['search_field']:'';
     $all_users = $obj->getAllUsers($search_field);


 }
?>
```

I removed your else part

Try this hope it will work for you

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131194/discussion-on-answer-by-amit-kumar-sahu-how-to-access-data-from-one-website-to-o).

Comment: sir i need your help if u r free then say yes or no

Comment: sir i have a web page in php which i want to share to others vis whats app,facebook linkedin, and on the same time when we press share button the automatically liked my facebook page if it is possible the tell me then i send my page

Answer (score 0):

You need to echo you response

```
if($btn_search =='Serach' && $btn_search !='') {
$search_field  =  isset($_GET['search_field'])?$_GET['search_field']:'';
$all_users = $obj->getAllUsers($search_field);


}else{ 
$all_users = $obj->getAllUsers();
$r = json_encode($all_users);
echo $r; 
}
```

Now hit the url.
AS per your comment you need the data of other project into your current project. So you need and CURL request to fetch the data from other project into your current one.

```
 $ch = curl_init();   
 $curlConfig = array(
 CURLOPT_URL            => "http://localhost/staff/home.php",
 CURLOPT_POST           => true,
 CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true, 
 );
 curl_setopt_array($ch, $curlConfig); 
 $result = curl_exec($ch);
 curl_close($ch);
 $decodeData = json_decode($result);
 print_r($decodeData);
```

Please try out the above code

Comment: ya hii nishant i have done this and m also getting json data but i want access same data in other project  and link is localhost/staff_json/index.php in that page i just want data and i have done code but data not showing here             <?php
$rs = file_get_contents('http://localhost/staff/home.php');
/*echo $rs;
die;*/
$obj = json_decode($rs);
echo "<pre>";
echo $obj;
//print_r($obj);


 ?>

Comment: sir i need yor help

Comment: sir i have a page where i want set the pagination can u help me??

Comment: Please visit the link  [ http://www.techumber.com/simple-pagination-with-php-mysql/  ]

Comment: sir i actully almost done but problem is that i am not able to implement my code in the desgine part

Comment: can i send my code u just implement my code in the desgin??

Comment: sir i have a web page in php which i want to share to others vis whats app,facebook linkedin, and on the same time when we press share button the automatically liked my facebook page if it is possible the tell me then i send my page

Comment: can i send my web page

Comment: Yes please share it

Comment: may i know your email is thats why i will send my web page

Comment: sir i just share my link plss open this   https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B8q6_T_xULZ3Yl83bnNuVDltMFU

Comment: here i have some issue can u help

Comment: what is issue you are facing the page is running fine.

Comment: tha page is running properly but i just want to share that page on whatsapp and facebook and eamil

Comment: can you put share button on this page thats why i can share this page on whats or facebook

Comment: hii nishat can u help me i m stucking in inquery form i just want to redirect my inquery form on thanks.php page