# Laravel: grab html from the view and send it as a mail attachment

Tags: php, laravel

I have a blade template that generates the content that I need:

*invoice.blade.php*

```
//nothing interesting here, just html
```

I have a route to access this view by a link:

*web.php*

```
Route::get('/invoice/{id}', function ($id) {return view('invoice.invoice')->with('id', $id);});
```

What is the better way to send the html file (which is generated by this route) by laravel mailer? I tried to do it in this way:

```
$file = file_get_contents(url('invoice/1'));    
Mail::send([], [], function ($message) use ($file) {
       ...
       $message->attach($file, [
          'as' => 'file-name',
          'mime' => 'text/html',
       ]);
    });
```

Mailer works fine, but get an error about maximum execution time exceeded for `file_get_contents` (I know it can be fixed by [`allow_url_fopen` PHP setting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8423404/php-file-get-contents-does-not-work-on-localhost)), also I know about [curl method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5522668/6479153), but it also not available for test for me right now by server settings. So my question is: do we have another way to implement this? Which way is better (faster)?

Comment: Use markdown mails instead. Good luck.

Comment: Markdown used for the mail content, not for attachments.

Comment: It was too late and I tried to be too clever. Good, that you found out how to do it. Wouldn't it be easier to generate PDF instead?

Comment: I need HTML file, not PDF. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solved by `view()->render()` and mailer `->attachData()` functions.

```
$file = view('invoice.invoice_inline', ['id' => $id])->render();
Mail::send([], [], function ($message) use ($file) {
   ...
   $message->attachData($file, 'filename.html', ['mime' => 'text/html']);
});
```

Comment: I definitely owe you a beer, my friend. What I am working on is a bit different, but close enough that this helped a ton.

Comment: This is really awesome. It works fine and faster than generating pdf