# why isn't file_put_contents working? (I use xampp)

Tags: php, file, xampp, file-put-contents

file_put_contents is not working for the following code? (I used xampp)

I try:

```
    $url = 
    'http://localhost/main_assets/images/company/news/142861-Spring-Break-main-pic.jpg';
      
    $file_name = basename($url);
    
    echo "url:";
    var_dump($url);
    
    echo "file_name:";
    var_dump($file_name);

    if (file_put_contents($file_name, file_get_contents($url)))
    {
        echo "File downloaded successfully";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "File downloading failed.";
    }
```

result:

```
url:
C:\xampp\htdocs\sitemaker\a_php_codes\controllers\testurl\ctrl_index.php:16:string 'http://localhost/main_assets/images/company/news/142861-Spring-Break-main-pic.jpg' (length=81)

file_name:
C:\xampp\htdocs\sitemaker\a_php_codes\controllers\testurl\ctrl_index.php:19:string '142861-Spring-Break-main-pic.jpg' (length=32)
File downloaded successfully
```

but there is no file in the following directory:

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\sitemaker\a_php_codes\controllers\testurl\
```

I can see the image when I enter the address to the browser;
result no file no error ...!!
I do some search but most result is because of permission issue.
I check the folders permission:
[image]
[image]

Comment: Apache look after access (or it should unless you have changed it)

Comment: Check your `htdocs` or `htdocs\sitemaker` directories… You're just giving a filename, not an absolute path, so PHP will save the file relative to whatever Apache's *working directory* is.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8423404/php-file-get-contents-does-not-work-on-localhost

Comment: @OMi Shah: thanks for your help but that link refer to get_content problem my problem is for put_content and the allow_url_fopen is on.

Comment: @RiggsFolly: I didn't get what you mean!

Comment: Where are you looking for the new picture file?

Comment: Did you read the comment from deceze?

Comment: @RiggsFolly: Thanks. The 'deceze' comment solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Many thanks to @deceze for the answer and @RiggsFolly for editing my question.
As I mentioned above I was looking in the folder that php file is running:

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\sitemaker\a_php_codes\controllers\testurl\
```

and expect the result file of the file_put_contents will appear in that folder but the file is in the htdocs folder (maybe the xampp default folder).
That was my problem and because of that, there is no error.
I use Predefined constants DIR and my problem is solved.
here is my final code:

```
  $url = 
'http://localhost/main_assets/images/company/news/142861-Spring-Break-main-pic.jpg';
  
$file_name = basename($url);

$filePath = __DIR__ . "\\" . $file_name; 

if (file_put_contents($filePath, file_get_contents($url)))
{
    echo "File downloaded successfully";
}
else
{
    echo "File downloading failed.";
}
```